# How to keep checking if a calculated number is an integer or not?

Tags: c, rsa, private-key

I would like to keep calculating `d` until it's an integer, if it is not an integer then increment a number by 1, if it is then return the integer. I have tried this but I keep getting the float number returned as an integer. (e.g. 19.4 will be returned as 19 but i just want to keep calculating it until i get an integer). I have tried the following code:

```
int calcD(int tn, int e){
    int z;
    float d;
    z = 1;
    while (true){
        d = (1+(z*tn))/e;
        if (fmodf(d, 1)!= 0){
            z++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    } 
    return d;
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: The return type is `int`, what do you expect?

Comment: Because it needs to return an int when d is an int, if d is not an int then keep incrementing z until it is.

Comment: I'm retagging this as a C question; it doesn't really have anything specifically to do with the "Objective" part of Objective-C.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code again, your problem is probably actually this line: `d = (1+(z*tn))/e;` since `z`, `tn` and `e` are all `int`s. This is going to do integer division, and just discard the remainder, so the value of `d` will *always* contain an integer value after this.

Comment: I concur with Charles, but this would have been easier to track down if you had provided an example input and output and explained how it was different from what you expected.

Comment: @trentcl Indeed. My first instinct was to answer the question being asked in the headline, which turned out not to be what was really needed here. Some sample input and output would have made this much more obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is how to tell if the result of division is an integer. That means checking if the numerator is a multiple of the denominator. That's pretty simple -- find the closest multiplier, multiply the denominator by it, and see if you get the numerator.

So:

```
while (true){
    num = 1 + (z * tn);
    d = num / e;
    if (d * e != num)
        z++;
    }else{
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Looking at his code, I don't think he really needs to be calculating `d` at all. Just checking whether `(1+(z*tn)) % e` is zero ought to do it and will perform better than doing a division and then a multiplication.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Are you able to explain why my previous code was not working as intended please? Thank you.

Comment: @JordanSavage The main problem is that you performed integer division, so of course your result is an integer. What you do with a result does not affect how that result is computer. When you divide two integers, you get an integer result because C uses integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the value against the value you get when you round it.

```
float f = ...
float precision = 0.00001;

if (fabsf(f - roundf(f)) < precision) {
    printf("integer\n");
} else {
    printf("not integer\n");
}
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: Is there some value that the algorithm above does not detect as an integer, even though it is one? If so, what is the value?